# Nuget.Core.dll documentation and/or tutorials

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have a task to manage packages from NuGet repositories and packages from C# code and I found that there is a Nuget.Core library that can help me with that without using of power shell reference in my C# code.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Nuget.Core/2.2.0

However, I wasn't able to find any good documentation reference or samples/tutorials of how to work with that library.

If you know any useful info about that, please, help me. Any links about that (samples, references, discussions) will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: any suggestion about that? Did anybody try to work with that library?

Comment: This is a useful question. The official documentation is hard to find.

Comment: It would seem the only documentation is one blog post. That's hardly adaquete if you want people to use the library. Also the package is missing a xml documentation file, so you have to work without Intellisense. http://blog.nuget.org/20130520/Play-with-packages.html

Comment: Polite request for documentation https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2425

Comment: Pretty unbelievable that there is no documentation given how popular of a package it is... Could have used some documentation this morning.